# Improving Keras classifier, dealing with dataset, getting wrong accuracy with Pandas, sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I want to build a classifier that takes into account multiple factors. I have been trying to follow tutorials and examples, but they all use data that is strictly numbers. The data I am using has both object and int types. I'm not sure if building a classifier would work with this kind of data so I turned everything to int type. I'm pretty sure I'm not building this classifier correctly, so I can use any help or an easier way to do this.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

df.drop('Name', axis=1, inplace=True)

obj_df = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).copy()
# print(obj_df.head())
obj_df["OUTPUT"] = obj_df["OUTPUT"].astype('category')
obj_df["TYPE_A"] = obj_df["TYPE_A"].astype('category')
obj_df["SIGNAL"] = obj_df["SIGNAL"].astype('category')
obj_df["A-B"] = obj_df["A-B"].astype('category')
# obj_df.dtypes
obj_df["OUTPUT_cat"] = obj_df["OUTPUT"].cat.codes
obj_df["TYPE_A_cat"] = obj_df["TYPE_A"].cat.codes
obj_df["SIGNAL_cat"] = obj_df["SIGNAL"].cat.codes
obj_df["A-B_cat"] = obj_df["A-B"].cat.codes
# print(obj_df.head())
df2 = df[['TRY', 'LOC', 'SPOT']]
df3 = obj_df[['OUTPUT_cat', 'TYPE_A_cat', 'SIGNAL_cat', 'A-B_cat']]
df4 = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1, sort=False)

target_column = ['OUTPUT_cat']
predictors = list(set(list(df4.columns))-set(target_column))
df4[predictors] = df4[predictors]/df4[predictors].max()
print(df4.describe())

X = df4[predictors].values
y = df4[target_column].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=40)
print(X_train.shape); print(X_test.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5000, activation='relu', input_dim=5))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# build the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=150)
```

Results:

```
Epoch 20/20
56/56 [==============================] - 4s 77ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.8165e-04
```

As seen, the accuracy is way off and super small. The examples I'm following all show values between 0 and 1 for accuracy (something like 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, or anything else above 0.01). Aside from pointing out the mistake, I'd also appreciate a bit more detail on how to deal with this particular dataset. Thank you.

Sample of data from CSV file:

```
         0    1    2        3          4       5    6     7
0     Name  TRY  LOC   OUTPUT     TYPE_A   SIGNAL  A-B  SPOT
1    inc 1    2   20   TYPE-1    TORPEDO   ULTRA    A   -21
2    inc 2    3   16   TYPE-2    TORPEDO     ILH    B   -14
3    inc 3    2   20  BLACK47    TORPEDO    LION    A    49
4    inc 4    3   12   TYPE-2  CENTRALPA    LION    A    25
5    inc 5    3   10   TYPE-2      THREE    LION    A   -21
6    inc 6    2   20   TYPE-2        ATF    LION    A   -48
7    inc 7    4    2  NIVEA-1        ATF    LION    B   -23
8    inc 8    3   16  NIVEA-1        ATF    LION    B    18
9    inc 9    3   18  BLENDER  CENTRALPA    LION    B    48
10   inc 10   4   20    DELCO        ATF    LION    B   -26
11   inc 11   3   20    VE248        ATF    LION    B    44
12   inc 12   1   20   SILVER  CENTRALPA    LION    B   -35
13   inc 13   2   20  CALVIN3     SEVENX    LION    B   -20
14   inc 14   3   14  DECK-BT  CENTRALPA    LION    B   -38
15   inc 15   4    4  10-LEVI    BERWYEN     OWL    B   -29
16   inc 16   4   14   TYPE-2        ATF     NOV    B   -31
17   inc 17   4   10     NYNY    TORPEDO     NOV    B    21
18   inc 18   2   20  NIVEA-1  CENTRALPA     NOV    B    45
19   inc 19   3   27   FMRA97    TORPEDO     NOV    B   -26
20   inc 20   4   18   SILVER        ATF     NOV    B   -46
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the encoding of the categorical features but your approach looks good on the first view. Your accuracy is very low but still between 0 and 1. Maybe try to add an validation split to the fitting and have a look on the generalization of the model.

Comment: I'll have to look into validation split and how to do all that. In terms of accuracy, what I meant was that it looks unreasonable. It should be something 0.75 or 0.25 or anything that's 0.01 or higher.

Comment: You cannot use softmax with one neuron, since it produces a constant value of 1.0, how many classes do you actually have?

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy By classes do you mean rows? If so, I have about 7800 rows. If you mean columns, I have about 60 columns, but only need 7 for this. Thanks

Comment: No, I do not mean columns, I mean number of classes, since you said you have a classification problem (that is why you are training a classifier, right?)

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy Oh, ok. Everything I have in terms of code is above. I'm using 6 inputs to determine one output

Comment: @J.Doe As you have one unit in the last layer, the activation function to be used in that layer is `sigmoid` and the loss must be `binary_crossentropy`